# Custom view CustomView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I know I could do as the warning directs me to; create 2- or 3-argument View constructor.

However, the `CustomView` is from a 3rd party SDK which is `final`, so I feel like I must use this one to take full advantage of the SDK. Anyhow, there's no chance to extend `final CustomView`.

Is there any workaround?

On a side note, the view I'm trying to use is 
[`MetaioSurfaceView`](http://doxygen.metaio.com/metaioSDK41/classcom_1_1metaio_1_1sdk_1_1_metaio_surface_view.html) by [Metaio](http://www.metaio.com/).

---

Below is the logcat message right after the crash:

```
A/WTF(18270): Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.suzi.application/com.suzi.application.CustomActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.metaio.sdk.MetaioSurfaceView
A/WTF(18270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.suzi.application/com.suzi.application.CustomActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.metaio.sdk.MetaioSurfaceView
A/WTF(18270):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
A/WTF(18270):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
A/WTF(18270):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
A/WTF(18270):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
A/WTF(18270):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
A/WTF(18270):   at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
A/WTF(18270):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have a custom view and customView has only one type of constructor like default constructor

when you add the custom view in xml than xml wants
 `CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`,
`CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`
 these type of constructor.

and if your custom view is belongs to 3rd party lib then you can only add by Java code by default constructor like `new CustomView();`

Comment: So except that I have to deal with the layout stuff by hard-coding, lack of the constructors (with AttributeSet argument) isn't evil?

Comment: ha ha yes, in  every 3 rd party custom view there should be three constructor at least

Comment: Great to hear there's no other issues. Thanks!